# Invalid account: #0 for network: ropsten - private key too short, expected 32 bytes

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgROr.png)

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */


const INFURA_PROJECT_ID = "3dxxxx";
const ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY = "e6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_PROJECT_ID}`,
      accounts: [`0x${ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  }
};
```

I deployed the contract to ropsten according to the example on the website, but an error was reported. The private key is greater than 32 bits

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you put "0x" before your private key. I had a similar error. Also, you can use Alchemy if you want. Everything else looks good in your config.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32031390)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and used an env file to store the constants.
So in my case, the error was solved by removing the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible fixes:

- Adding a 0x to the private key
- Converting or casting the private key from .env file to a string with `String`, `toString()`, and string interpolation `$0x{process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`
- Checking that I was calling the test from the correct directory
- Checking that the .env file was in the correct (project root) directory
- Checking that the wallet software gave me the full private key and not a partial key

But what fixed the issue was importing:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
```

at the top of the `hardhat.config.js` file